# Storing Jquery reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Is it possible to store the reference to an element in an array or object without having a unique ID on the element?

I am having trouble with storing a subtable in another table so I can reference it later. I get the table by class with this code:

```
$(this).parent('tr').parent().find('.tableSomeTable');
```

Is the only solution to have unique id's on each element and use the .selector method?

More of my code. Abit simplified.

```
  var rows = [];
  var historyLoad;

 $(document).on("click", '.details-control', function (e) {
    var t = $(this);
    var tr = t.closest('tr');
    var row = t.parent().parent().parent().DataTable().row(tr);
    var id = t.closest('tr').attr('id');

    var object = {
        id: id,
        btnHistory: t.parent('tr').next().find('#btnHistory'),
        tblHistory: t.parent('tr').parent().find('.tableHistory'),
        historyLoad: historyLoad
    };

   if ($.inArray(id, rows) > -1) {
     loadData = false;
   }
   else {
       loadData = true; 
       loadHistory(object);
       rows.push(object);
    }
};
```

Here is where I am having trouble retrieving the correct elements. And I also want to save the ajaxHistory element to my object (which is working fine).
This code is not working, but if I change it to $(result.btnHistory.btnHistory.selector) I get the object. But this doesn't seem to work very good with multiple rows.

```
  function loadHistory(result) {
      result.ajaxHistory = $.ajax({
              ...
         beforeSend: function () {
            $(result.btnHistory).html(<loading txt>);
            $(result.tblHistory).find('tbody').html(<loading txt>);
        },
           ....
         success: function (data) {
            if (data.TotalRecordCount > 0) {
                $(result.tblHistory).find('tbody').html('');
                $.each(data.Records, function (e, o) {
                     $(result.tblHistory).find('tbody').append(<data>)
                  });
            }
            else {
                $(result.tblHistory).find('tbody').html(<txt no records>);
            }
            $(result.btnHistory).html(<txt loading done>));
        },
```

Comment: `var mysubtable = $(this).parent('tr').parent().find('.tableSomeTable');`?

Comment: What "trouble" are you having? (Yes, you can do that; jQuery objects are just objects.)

Comment: Hmm I probably explained it abit porly, I will try and create an example.

Comment: Updated my question. I am not that good with jquery/javascript so might be something stupid that I am not seeing :/

Comment: Was some problems with my formatting method. Worked if I mapped the objects after the format method was beeing executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you are trying to find the parent table, try

```
    var $myObj = $(this).closest('table.tableSomeTable');
```

instead of navigating parents.

As far as storing the jQuery reference, define a variable and then store it.  The above will store the object in $myObj but that is locally scoped.  If you need a global variable then define it globally and just assign it here.  If you want to define it as a property within an object then define it that way.  It really comes down to a scope question at this point.

EDIT:  Just saw your added content.

<s>First off, don't name it 'object'.  This may run into key word issues.  Use var myObj or similar instead.</s>  Next, object.btnHistory is a reference to a jQuery object.  So, when you pass it to loadHistory, you do not need to apply the $(...) again.  Just use the reference directly:  result.btnHistory.html(...).  A good habit to get into is prepending you jQuery variables with $ so you remember it is already a jQuery variable.

Comment: `object` is not a reserved word in JavaScript and at this point it will never be.

Comment: How would I define a property within that object? And how could I use it again?

Comment: As you have it, btnHistory is a property within object.  (My initial post was made before you added more content.)  Try taking out the $ around $(result.btnHistory) in the AJAX and see how it works.  If it still isn't working then we'll look deeper.

Comment: If I dont use the selector and just save it to my object with btnHistory: $(this).parent('tr').next().find('#btnHistory') I am just getting undefined in my load method. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/qARLZCA.png from             result.btnHistory.html('Test');
            console.log(result.btnHistory.html());

Comment: In your html, what kind of element is the onclick with .details-control on?  A TD?  And if you could post some of the html for the table that would help.

Comment: Yes, it's a TD. You can see a simplified HTML setup of the table here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html And I am having subtables and buttons in the row details section for each row. Which are beeing returned when you expand a row.

Comment: Ok, next step in debuggin, add a debugger line between the ``var id =``  and the ``var object =``   so that we can check and see how the selectors are working.  Also, I'd recommend removing the historyLoad property from object.  That is a global variable so there is no need to pass it.  Plus, it is never given a value which is why it shows as undefined in the error screen shot you gave.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84723/discussion-between-nurdyguy-and-stibay).

Answer (score 1):

The [`.find()` method](https://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a [**jQuery object**](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).  So the answer is, yes, you can store this return object in a variable:

```
var $yourObject = $(this).parent('tr').parent().find('.tableSomeTable');
```